# get value of images tags from list

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, exif

I am using python to extract image metadata. The images are placed inside a folder and the images are added to list in python. After that I am extracting tags and values from those images but it is saying that AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get' at ***value = val1.get(tagid)***

The code is also attached

```
exifdata = []

images_length = len(imagesList)

for i in range(images_length):
    metavar = imagesList[i].getexif
    exifdata.insert(i,metavar)

exif_length = len(exifdata)

for i in range(exif_length):
    for tagid in iter(exifdata):

        # getting the tag name instead of tag id
        tagname = TAGS.get(tagid, tagid)
    
        # passing the tagid to get its respective value
        val1 = exifdata[i]
        value = val1.get(tagid)
        
        # printing the final result
        print(f"{tagname:25}: {value}")
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `metavar = imagesList[i].getexif` does not call the method, so the method itself gets stored in `exifdata` and later retrieved. This is a simple typo.

Comment: Use `metavar = imagesList[i].getexif()` with the parentheses at the end in order to actually call the function.